Host a python application on IIS windows server
Im trying to set my flask web application on IIS - Windows server 2019
My web app containing a requirements.txt file which i dont see any option on IIS to set it as build command like pip install -r requirements.txt and then any option to set the starting point python app.py anywhere.
Is there a way to achieve all these? I know i have plently options like AWS but for now i have to host the app on the windows server.

https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ You might install the packages to the global Python interpreter and then follow the steps.

By configuring IIS to use HttpPlatformHandler and specifying the Python executable and your Flask application's entry point, you can host your Flask application on Windows Server 2019 using IIS.

As said by the Lex Li. You have a few options:
1 - Use a configuration via HttpPlatformHandler as shown in the suggested link: tldr https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/
2 - Provide a .sh script to carry out the necessary processes in the terminal until the application starts. It would be something like:
#!/bin/bash

# Flask application directory
app_dir="/path/to/your/flask/app"

# IIS virtual directory
iis_vdir="/path/to/your/iis/vdir"

# IIS website name
iis_site_name="YourSiteName"

# IIS User
iis_user="IIS_USER"

# IIS user password
iis_password="IIS_PASSWORD"

# pip requirements file
requirements_file="$app_dir/requirements.txt"

# WSGI configuration file
wsgi_file="$app_dir/wsgi.py"

# Install dependencies with pip
echo "Installing dependencies with pip..."
pip install -r "$requirements_file"

# Create IIS virtual directory if it does not exist
if [ ! -d "$iis_vdir" ]; then
     mkdir "$iis_vdir"
fi

# Copy application files to the IIS virtual directory
echo "Copying application files to IIS virtual directory..."
cp -r "$app_dir/*" "$iis_vdir"

# Configure HttpPlatformHandler in IIS
echo "Configuring HttpPlatformHandler in IIS..."
appcmd set site "$iis_site_name" /applicationpool:"DefaultAppPool" /processmodel:"managed" /managedhandler:"*;.py" /runtimeversion:"v4.0"
appcmd set site "$iis_site_name" /bindings /binding:"http://*:80" /protocol:"http" /certificateType:"None" /physicalPath:"$iis_vdir" /authType:"basic"
appcmd set site "$iis_site_name" /bindings /binding:"https://*:443" /protocol:"https" /certificateType:"SelfSigned" /physicalPath:"$iis_vdir" /authType:"basic"
appcmd set site "$iis_site_name" /log /iis:"CustomLog" /fileformat:"W3C" /fields:"date time s-ip cs-method s-uri sc-status time-taken" /additionalFields:"x-powered -by: Python" /outputformat:"TXT" /filepath:"$iis_vdir/logs/w3c.log"

# Grant permissions to IIS user
echo "Granting permissions to IIS user..."
chown -R "$iis_user":"$iis_group" "$iis_vdir"

# Restart the IIS website
echo "Restarting the IIS website..."
iisreset /stop "$iis_site_name"
iisreset /start "$iis_site_name"

echo "Flask application successfully initialized in IIS!"

3 - Use a Docker container to compartmentalize the entire application and make it accessible via IIS. To configure the load balancer for a docker container using IIS you can do something like:
Make sure the Dockerfile exposes the correct port for the Flask application. The default port for Flask applications is 5000.
Add the following command to the end of the Dockerfile to set the FLASK_APP environment variable:
Dockerfile
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py


Build the Docker image:

Use the following command to build the Docker image:
bash
docker build -t flask-app .


Run the Docker container:

Run the Docker container with the following option to expose port 5000:
bash
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 flask-app


Configure IIS load balancer:
Open IIS Manager on your server. In the left pane, right-click on
"Sites" and select "Add Site".
In the "Add Site" dialog box, enter a name for your site (e.g. "FlaskApp") and click "Next."
In the "Select Binding Header Type" dialog box, select "http" and click "Next".
In the "Add New Binding" dialog box, enter your server's IP address and
port 80 (or the port you want to use for your website) and click
"Add".
Click "Finish" to finish creating the website.
In the left pane, right-click "Sites" and select the website you just created.
In the center pane, double-click "Network Load Balancer."
In the "Network Load Balancer" dialog box, click "Add".
In the "Add IP Address Host" dialog box, enter your server's hostname and port 5000 (the port you exposed in the Dockerfile) and click "Add".
Click "OK" to save the changes.


thank for the answer. do you have any full source for the .sh step..seems good to me

No, i used an LLM to generate this .sh. But probably you can use that way with a few changes.
